# Following steps to construct a DAWG results in a Trie. Why?

Tags: search, full-text-search, trie, finite-automata, directed-acyclic-graphs

I'm trying to implement a set of functions that create a DAWG directly in linear time for some search functionality I'm coding for a personal project. I read [this paper](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.117.9069) which happens to detail the idea behind a DAWG, and even provides pseudocode for its construction in linear time!

However, following the pseudo-code seems to yield (in my eyes) a trie-like structure. Specifically, it doesn't seem that suffixes are explicitly shared (actually connected by edges in the graph). Instead they're represented by suffix pointers which don't really have a bearing on the actual traversal of the graph.

For example, take a look at this picture of a DAWG for the words in the set `{tap, taps, top, tops}` (from the [DAWG Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_word_graph)):

[image]

Now, compare that with the structure you get following these steps detailed in the aforementioned paper (doing it by hand with this set of words takes a negligible amount of  time):

```
Note: Edges are labeled by letters
      Nodes are labeled by the concatenation of the labels of the primary edges
      used to reach them
      Suffix pointers are not visually represented on the graph

      primary edges:   solid edges used to traverse graph
      secondary edges: dotted edges implying a suffix relationship between
                       the letter labeling the edge and the substring 
                       represented by the target node

builddawg(S)
    1. Create a node named source.
    2. Let activenode be source.
    3. For each word w of S do:
        A. For each letter 'a' of w do:
            Let activenode be update (activenode, a).
        B. Let activenode be source.
    4. Return source.


update (activenode, a)
    1. If activenode has an outgoing edge labeled 'a', then
        A. Let newactivenode be the node that this edge leads to.
        B. If this edge is primary, return newactivenode.
        C. Else, return split (activenode, newactivenode).
    2. Else
        A. Create a node named newactivenode.
        B. Create a primary edge labeled 'a' from activenode to newactivenode.
        C. Let currentnode be activenode.
        D. Let suflxnode be undefined.
        E. While currentnode isn’t source and sufixnode is undefined do:
            i. Let currentnode be the node pointed to by the suffix
               pointer of currentnode.
            ii. If currentnode has a primary outgoing edge labeled 'a',
                then let sufixnode be the node that this edge leads to.
            iii. Else,if currentnode has a secondary outgoing edge labeled 'a' then
                a. Let childnode be the node that this edge leads to.
                b. Let suffixnode be split (currentnode, childnode).
            iv. Else, create a secondary edge from currentnode to newactivenode
                labeled 'a'.
        F. If sufixnode is still undefined, let suffixnode be source.
        G. Set the suffix pointer of newactivenode to point to sufixnode.
        H. Return newactivenode.


split (parentnode, childnode)
    1. Create a node called newchildnode.
    2. Make the secondary edge from parentnode to childnode into
       a primary edge from parentnode to newchildnode (with the same label).
    3. For every primary and secondary outgoing edge of childnode,
       create a secondary outgoing edge of newchildnode with the
       same label and leading to the same node.
    4. Set the suffix pointer of newchildnode equal to that of childnode.
    5. Reset the suffix pointer of childnode to point to newchildnode.
    6. Let currentnode be parentnode.
    7. While currentnode isn’t source do:
        A. Let currentnode be the node pointed to by the 
           suffix pointer of currentnode.
        B. If currentnode has a secondary edge to childnode,
           then make it a secondary edge to newchildnode (with the same label).
        C. Else, break out of the while loop.
    8. Return newchildnode.
```

The structure I get is not equivalent to that pictured above. It, in fact, looks almost identical to a trie except for the extra nodes resulting from converting secondary edges in to primary edges. The trie equivalent to the DAWG above is:

[image]

Am I just applying the algorithm wrong, are there several types of DAWGS, or am I just misunderstanding what a DAWG is supposed to look like?

Most of the papers i've looked at detailing a DAWGs have structures that seem to be created by the algorithm, but most of the materials online that i've read (and pictues i've seen) have actual edges connecting common suffixes. I don't know what to believe, or if they're actually equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

I believe I found a solution.

After building the DAWG, you can iterate through the nodes top to bottom, and delete the sub-trees of those with `suffixPointer != source`, connecting them directly to the node that `suffixPointer` points to.